# Missing utf-8 symbols in font -> how to combine multiple fonts into one [Linux]?

Tags: linux, fonts

TL;DR- How to combine F0,F1,F2... fonts, so for each possible utf-8 symbol the one is taken available in font with lowest index? (or skipped if not present in any)

I come across following problem, captured in  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389035/9689 , basically :

- My desired font F0 did not contain utf-8 symbols I wanted to use and does not provide mechanism to failover to other F1, F2... fonts for missing symbols

I'd like to use (with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) under Linux) some font F0, but unfortunately, utf-8 symbols I want to use are present in other fonts, let's name them F1, F2, F3...

What I've found is that some other (than [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org)) font renderings (like LibreOffice Writer, Browsers, etc...) does not have this problem and when utf-8 symbol is missing in font F0 than they automatically failover to another font. However [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) does not have such failover capabilities.

Therefore: How to make such Uber-Font F* , that would be combination of F0, F1, F2, F3... list of fonts, created by taking each symbol from first font where it's available?

Comment: Perhaps you should look into using Cairo and Pango for your image annotation needs.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of software responsible for choosing a fallback font is the `fontconfig` library. As you noticed ImageMagick doesn't fontconfig, thus there's no fallback.

> How to make such Uber-Font F* , that would be combination of F0, F1, F2, F3... list of fonts, created by taking each symbol from first font where it's available?

There are tools that allow to extract the "essence" of a font into XML format and back again, namely the `ttx` tool of [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools).

Thanks to being XML you can combine the font data with readily available tools and/or libraries. This you can then convert back.